# Multi-processing with decorated methods - the parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multi-processing on windows 10 with Python 3.10.1.
If the method has a decoration, then this code fails:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def profiler(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result

    return wrap

@profiler
def go_around(num):
    print(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=go_around, args=(1,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I'm getting this error:

> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 102, in spawn_main
> source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess(
> OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Note that this used to work on python 2.7.
Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce it on python 3.9, but I got completely another exception: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'profiler.<locals>.wrap'`.

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/EdwinChan/3c13d3a746bb3ec5082f) and the comments below.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in either Python 2.7 or 3.8. Although the error messages are slightly different, they both boil down to the inability to pickle a local function (`wrap()` presumably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python pickling needs to pull the original function in order to re-construct the decorated function, and it's no longer in the namespace (because it's already been decorated.) using the decorator `functools.wraps` on the wrapped function stores a copy of the original function in the __dict__ of the new function so it can be accessed later. There's some edge cases where this may not work (classes..) but for simple decorators, it should work:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import functools

def profiler(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("I profiled your function for you :)")
        return result
    return wrap

@profiler
def go_around(num):
    print(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=go_around, args=(1,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9336868/3220135) answer discusses things a bit further..

Comment: Great, This works and I do not need to change the usage of my python package. thanks

Comment: iirc multiprocessing alternatives that use `dill` instead of `pickle` also won't run into this problem. I tend to try and not stray too far away from the standard libraries however mostly just because it's very well known, stable (not bug free though).